# omniauth-facebook приходит неполный response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

С аунтификацией ВК все работает, сейчас не получается с фейсбуком
**omniauth_controller.rb**

```
class OmniauthController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_user
  before_action :current_user_resorces

  def create
    if @user
      @account[user: @user]
    else
      @user = User.create(auth_params)
      @account[user_id: @user]
    end
    binding.pry
    @account.save
    session[:current_user_id] = @user.token
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def current_user_resorces
    @account = Account.find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash[:uid],
                                         provider: auth_hash[:provider],
                                         email: auth_hash[:info][:email])
    @user = User.find_by(email: auth_hash[:info][:email])
  end

  private

  def auth_params
    password = "#{rand(100)}_sample_password_#{rand(100)}"
    {
      first_name: auth_hash[:extra][:raw_info][:first_name],
      last_name: auth_hash[:extra][:raw_info][:last_name],
      token: auth_hash[:credentials][:token],
      email: auth_hash[:info][:email],
      password: password,
      password_confirmation: password
    }
  end

  protected

  def auth_hash
    request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end
end
```

**omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['facebook_key'], ENV['facebook_secret'], scope: 'email'
  provider :vkontakte, ENV['vk_key'], ENV['vk_secret'], scope: 'email'
end
```

**response**

```
From: /home/andrey/dev/note_work/app/controllers/omniauth_controller.rb @ line 12 OmniauthController#create:

     5: def create
     6:   if @user
     7:     @account[user: @user]
     8:   else
     9:     @user = User.create(auth_params)
    10:     @account[user_id: @user]
    11:   end
 => 12:   binding.pry
    13:   @account.save
    14:   session[:current_user_id] = @user.token
    15:   redirect_to root_path
    16: end

[1] pry(#<OmniauthController>)> auth_hash
=> {"provider"=>"facebook",
 "uid"=>"1595189064132754",
 "info"=>{"name"=>"Андрей Шостик", "image"=>"http://graph.facebook.com/1595189064132754/picture"},
 "credentials"=>
  {"token"=>
    "CAASSzI1FNZBIBALpKPJoXXyQuZB0697rVBdgVXmpgrY6PsQRFWUTBjbT01hgzygVFw5uwxFT7keFEiwzaWWHfm50mMINWwcmQlofoEYkFDD6eUKMyhSUI4KvIlT7Uzx5sHZBiBvhxqIYEFUlwrKp4SGLTCrpnbdKY8jZA1AC1ZB4qU1V2ShluEe5Ehi0mfCTyZA4FXlJdysAZDZD",
   "expires_at"=>1465980629,
   "expires"=>true},
 "extra"=>{"raw_info"=>{"name"=>"Андрей Шостик", "id"=>"1595189064132754"}}}
[2] pry(#<OmniauthController>)> @user
=> #<User:0x007f16786db880
 id: nil,
 login: nil,
 email: nil,
 first_name: nil,
 last_name: nil,
 password_digest: "$2a$10$KJJJQ7.Pn5UDVLQ.yVXeDed7tUGdbiiSI.91Vq8FtvXmFQUUxEb4O",
 token:
  "CAASSzI1FNZBIBALpKPJoXXyQuZB0697rVBdgVXmpgrY6PsQRFWUTBjbT01hgzygVFw5uwxFT7keFEiwzaWWHfm50mMINWwcmQlofoEYkFDD6eUKMyhSUI4KvIlT7Uzx5sHZBiBvhxqIYEFUlwrKp4SGLTCrpnbdKY8jZA1AC1ZB4qU1V2ShluEe5Ehi0mfCTyZA4FXlJdysAZDZD",
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
[3] pry(#<OmniauthController>)>
```

Comment: вы какие ключи в настройке для фб указали? Насколько я помню так должен быть user_email включён